# Pulling out keywords using standard command line utilities?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression

As an example, this is the pronunciation of "when" according to Wiktionary. enPR, IPA and X-SAMPA are different schemes for showing pronunciations.

```
when:* {{a|US}} {{enPR|wĕn|hwĕn}}, {{IPA|/wɛn/|/ʍɛn/}}, {{X-SAMPA|/wEn/|/WEn/}}
```

I'd like to pull out the keyword `when` and its two IPA pronunciations, and put them on separate lines:

```
when wɛn
when ʍɛn
```

There may be one, two or more IPA pronunciations of a word, and there may or may not be enPR or X-SAMPA pronunciations.

I'm thinking PHP, lists within lists, but this seems to be overkill, and I don't want the users to have to install it if possible. Is there a way to do this in awk, sed, cut or other standard Unix command line utility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`, you could write it as:

```
sed '/\([^:]*\):.*{IPA|\([^}]*\).*/!d;s//\1 \2/;s,/,,g;:1
     s/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1\n\2 /;t1'
```

#### Breakdown (by @slm, thanks)

The above command can be broken down as follows:

1. Parse input into `when: ... {IPA|...}` and delete non-matching lines.

   In `/pattern/!d; s//repl/`

   We [d]iscard the lines that do not[!] match the pattern, and then reuse the same pattern in the next [s]substitution command (an empty pattern means reusing the last pattern). Instead of [d]eleting the non-matching lines, we could have left them untouched by using `b` instead of `d`, or if we know that all the lines match the pattern, we could use `s/pattern/repl/` directly.

   ```
   /\([^:]*\):.*{IPA|\([^}]*\).*/
   ```

   That pattern splits the data up into 2 chunks. The first chunk is `when:`. This bit of code, `\([^:]*\):` says to take all the characters until you encounter a `:` and to save it in a temp. variable (`\1`).

   All the characters between the `:` up to and including the `{IPA|` are skipped. The next bit that's saved is everything after the `IPA|`. This is done by this block of code, `\([^}]*\)`, which says to save all the code until a `}` is encountered. This is saved in variable (`\2`).

   **NOTE:** In `sed` any time you want to save a chunk of the string you can wrap it in parentheses. They need to be escaped with a `\` so that `sed` knows you don't mean a literal paren. Like so: `\( savethis \)`.

   #### example

   ```
   $ sed 's/\([^:]*\):.*{IPA|\([^}]*\).*/\1 \2/;' sample.txt
   when /wɛn/|/ʍɛn/
   ```
2. Remove all forward slashes (`/`)

   This one looks more complicated because it's using an alternate separator. You'd typically use the form `s///g`, but `sed` let's you make up separators on the fly, so we're using commas instead (`s,,,g`). This block searches for `/` and replaces them with nothing.

   #### example

   ```
   $ sed '/\([^:]*\):.*{IPA|\([^}]*\).*/!d;s//\1 \2/;s,/,,g;' sample.txt
   when wɛn|ʍɛn
   ```
3. Iterate through each IPA

   ```
    :1 s/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1\n\2 /;t1
   ```

   This is by far the most complicated component of this solution. It's hard to see what's going on but this block is a conditional branch.

   ```
    :label command(s) t label
   ```

   The label is `:1` the command(s) are `s/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1\n\2 /;` and the `t label` is the "test" that sees if the previous command modified the pattern space. If so then jump to label `1`, hence the `t1`.
4. The command inside the loop

   If we take the `label ... loop` out for a sec, and increase our IPA example so that it has 3, you can see what's going on a little bit better.

   ```
   {{IPA|/wɛn/|/ʍɛn/|/blah/}}
   ```

   We'll end up with this, using the previous commands to this point.

   ```
   when wɛn|ʍɛn|blah
   ```

   If we now run this:

   ```
   $ echo "when wɛn|ʍɛn|blah" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1 \2 /;'
   ```

   We get this:

   ```
   when wɛn|ʍɛn
   when blah
   ```

   Can you see what it's doing now? Yeah me neither, so let's simplify a little more, and take the newline (`\n`) out and swap in some shorter strings.

   #### simpler example

   ```
   $ echo "X C1|C2|C3" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1 \2 /;'
   X C1|C2 X C3
   ```

   Now what's going on here is that the code `\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|` is clever in the sense that it's nesting the parens so that they're like this `( ( ) )`. What's being matched on the inside parens is anything that's not a space. This get's the `when` string. The outer parens match everything up to the last pipe (`|`).

   The other interesting thing with this code snippet is that the parens are ordered so that the outer ones get stored in `\1` while the inner ones are `\2`. This is because `sed` numbers them based on the order in which they're encountered.

   You can convince yourself of this by extending the snippet with additional `\1`'s and `\2`'s.

   ```
   $ echo "X C1|C2|C3" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1 \1 \1 /;'
   X C1|C2 X C1|C2 X C1|C2 C3

   $ echo "X C1|C2|C3" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1 \2 \2 /;'
   X C1|C2 X X C
   ```

   So the command inside the loop is basically taking the `X` 2 times. Once as part of the whole `X C1|C2` (outside parens) and a second time as anything up to the space (inside parens).
5. Back to the conditional branch

   OK so the branch is basically going to call the command in #5, for IPA's where there are more than 2. `sed`'s branch construct will keep re-running the command until the command no longer modifies the substitution, at which point it stops.

   #### example

   ```
   $ echo "X C1|C2|C3" | sed ':1 s/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1\n\2 /; t1'
   X C1
   X C2
   X C3
   ```

Hopefully the above will help other passerby's to this answer in the future.

Comment: Don't know how you figured this out, and can't make heads or tails of it, but it works!

Comment: @YiminRong - yes Stephane's got some of the best answers on the site. He and Gilles.

Comment: @YiminRong - if you start to break it down you can see how it works.

Comment: Do you care if someone expands on your answers to explain how they work?

Comment: Why does this also work? `sed '/\([^:]*\):.*{IPA|\([^}]*\).*/!d;s//\1 \2/;s,/,,g;s/\(\([^ ]*\).*\)|/\1\n\2 /;` What role does `:1` and `t1` play?

Comment: @slm, it's to iterate if there are more than two pronunciations. Please feel free to expand.

Answer (score 2):

With perl inside a perl script (processing `STDIN`)

```
while(<>) {
    if(/^([^:]+):.*{{IPA\|([^}]+)}}/) { 
        print "$1 $_\n" foreach(split /\|/, $2); 
    }
}
```

or on the command line (piping)

```
perl -ne ' if(/^([^:]+):.*{{IPA\|([^}]+)}}/) { print "$1 $_\n" foreach(split /\|/, $2); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash and grep

```
line='when:* {{a|US}} {{enPR|wĕn|hwĕn}}, {{IPA|/wɛn/|/ʍɛn/}}, {{X-SAMPA|/wEn/|/WEn/}}'
IFS=$': \t' read -ra words <<< "$line"
for item in "${words[@]}"; do
    if [[ $item == "{{IPA|"* ]]; then
        grep -o '/[^/]\+/' <<< "$item" | while read -r pronunc; do
             echo "${words[0]} ${pronunc//\//}"
        done
    fi
done
```